# Two way data binding with :model.sync when prop has get() and set()

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a computed property that I use as `v-model` on an input. I've written it this way to get reactivity -- this calls my `setText` Vuex action which I then can get with my getter `text`. It looks like this:

```
text: {
   get() {
     return this.text;
   },
   set(value) {
     this.setText(value);
   },
 },
```

and I use it in my input like this:

```
<input class="input" type="text" v-model="text" />
```

This works well. Now, I've put the `input` in question into a separate component which I use. This means I have to pass the `text` v-model as props, which I do with `:model.sync`, like so:

`<myInput :model.sync="text"/>`

and in the `myInput` component I use the props like so:

```
<input class="input" id="search-order" type="text" :value="model" @input="$emit('update:model', $event)">
```

But this doesn't seem to work at all, whenever I type into the input, the input says: `[object InputEvent]` and if I try to see and the value of `model` it's `{isTrusted: true}`. I'm assuming it's because of the getters and setters I have on my computed property. How do I pass these down to the child component?

Comment: `$emit('update:model', $event.target.value)`

Comment: Wow. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `.sync` modifier you can support the `v-model` directive in your custom component. `v-model` is syntax sugar for a `value` prop and an `input` event.

To support `v-model` just make sure your custom component has a `value` prop and emits an `input` event with the new value: `this.$emit('input', event.target.value)`.

Here is an example of a `<BaseInput>` component I use, it's written in TypeScript:

```
<template>
  <input
    :type="type"
    :value="value"
    class="input"
    v-on="listeners"
  >
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'BaseInput',

  props: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: 'text',
    },

    value: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: '',
    },

    lazy: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },

    number: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },

    trim: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },

  computed: {
    modelEvent(): string {
      return this.lazy ? 'change' : 'input'
    },

    parseModel(): (value: string) => string | number {
      return (value: string) => {
        if (this.type === 'number' || this.number) {
          const res = Number.parseFloat(value)
          // If the value cannot be parsed with parseFloat(),
          // then the original value is returned.
          return Number.isNaN(res) ? value : res
        } else if (this.trim) {
          return value.trim()
        }
        return value
      }
    },

    listeners(): Record<string, Function | Function[]> {
      return {
        ...this.$listeners,
        [this.modelEvent]: (event: HTMLElementEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
          this.$emit(this.modelEvent, this.parseModel(event.target.value)),
      }
  },
})
</script>
```

You can use it like so:

```
<BaseInput v-model="text" />
```